# Setting custom UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

Hello everyone I have a problem with my custom navigation bar.

I needed to create a custom navigation bar and this was to be used in several view controllers so i created it as a category for UIViewController and Used the following code for creating the customisation i needed.

```
- (void)setCustomLabel:(NSString *)labelText
{
    UILabel *navigationLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,10,40,40)];
    [navigationLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    navigationLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Humanist 521 BT-Bold" size:15.0];
    navigationLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
    navigationLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    navigationLabel.text = labelText;

    navigationLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:241.0/255.0 blue:241.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    navigationLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);

    [navigationLabel sizeToFit];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navigationLabel];

    [navigationLabel release];

}
```

On first view there are 2 buttons signIn and Register when i click on signIn button it will take me to signIn View and when i click on register button it will take me to Register view.
I created 2 ViewControllers and set the navigationBarLabel in both views as Register and SignIn using the code :

```
[self setCustomLabel:@"REGISTER"];
```

and

```
[self setCustomLabel:@"SIGN IN"];
```

The views would have a title displayed as [image]

and

[image]

and it does look this way when i first run the application and click on either register or signIn Button but if i click on any of the 2 buttons navigate to the register or signIn view and then i go back and click on the second button the navigation bar changes to

[image]

Please help me out i have been at this for a very long time i set the navigation bar in viewDidAppear and i have also tried setting it to nil

```
[self setCustomLabel:nil];
```

in viewWillDisappear and in viewDidDisappear . I am new to iPhone development help me ou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are **adding** the label to the navigation bar. Since it is the same navigation bar no matter how many views you go to, it just keeps adding new labels to the bar and leaves them there.

The way that I see it you have two options to fix this:

1. You can create a singular label one time and have it always on the navigation bar and just set its text in the method so that it always has the correct text and set it to hidden when you do not want it to be visible.
2. You can do the same thing you are doing, but add a `tag` to the label and before creating the new label, you can iterate through the `NavigationBar`'s subviews and remove the old label by checking the tags.

Comment: Thank you Jsdodgers i set it up to remove from the view in viewDidDisappear and it worked like a charm thank you so much.....:)

Answer (score 0):

You're not removing the label from the navigationbar when you're addign a new one.
Perhaps you should try calling `[navigationLabel removeFromSuperview]` on it when you wish to set a new one. (This means you probably have to store it in an @property)

example:

header file:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) UILabel *navigationLabel;
```

Implementation file:

```
@synthesize navigationLabel

- (void)setCustomLabel:(NSString *)labelText {
    if (self.navigationLabel) [self.navigationLabel removeFromSuperview];

    self.navigationLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,10,40,40)];
    [self.navigationLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    self.navigationLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Humanist 521 BT-Bold" size:15.0];
    self.navigationLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
    self.navigationLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationLabel.text = labelText;

    self.navigationLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0/255.0 green:241.0/255.0 blue:241.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.navigationLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);

    [self.navigationLabel sizeToFit];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.navigationLabel];

    [self.navigationLabel release];

}
```

Comment: Sorry but i can not add property since it is a category.